# printing grid with specified dimension with n*n

Tags: c

I am trying to create a grid of, for example, 4 rows and 4 columns.The dimension of the grid is n*n size. I have tried the following piece of code which is working fine for 3 rows only as I am trying to print 4*4 grid. But the last grid (4th is this case) is never printed. I mean as soon as the 3rd grid is printed the loop exits. I would appreciate if anyone help me to figure out why it is taking only 3 rows with 4 columns rather than 4 rows with 4 columns? Here is what I have tried so far,

```
void main()
{
int n, i, j;
scanf("%d", &n);
char grid[n][n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        scanf("%c", &grid[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] == '9')
            printf("X");
            else
            printf("%c", grid[i][j]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possibly because `scanf("%c", ...)` will also read the `newline` chars.

Comment: @WeatherVane, that should be an answer

Comment: Or `scanf("%d", n)` will read more than 1 digit

Comment: If you enter data for each line, each followed by `newline`, you will have read the `newline` following the first `scanf("%d",...)`, then 3 lines of 4 chars + 1 `newline`, total 16 chars.

Comment: can anyone help me how to print 4 * 4 grid?

Comment: Note that you could also read (for example) four chars at once: `scanf("%4c", &grid[i])`

Comment: Thanks a lot @user3121023 ! It worked now!!

Comment: @Angela please take a look at [this question](/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf) that has a good discussion on why you should probably use `fgets` and `sscanf` to do this as opposed to `scanf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very quick hack to get your code working, as I believe you expect.  Including the `\n` in scanf is probably not the best way of doing this, please see [this answer](/a/14566195/2487517):

```
int n, i, j;
scanf("%d\n", &n);
char grid[n][n];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        scanf("%c", &grid[i][j]);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (grid[i][j] == '9')
            printf("X");
        else
            printf("%c", grid[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Using this as input:

```
4
1234234534564567
```

This is the output:

```
1234
2345
3456
4567
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
scanf("%c", ...)
```

will also read any `newline` chars typed, including the one following the previous

```
scanf("%d", ...)
```

So if you enter each line's data followed by a `newline`, you will have read 1 + 3 * 5 = 16 characters after the third line.

I suggest you input four strings instead, and copy each character to the array, using `scanf("%s", ...)`. That way, all whitespace will be ignored (except the final `newline` will remain in the input buffer).